# How to show result of POCO(class) file in winform label/textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework

i am new to c#. I have a doubt. Lets take an real time example

1. Suppose i have a login winform with filed username and password and a button.
2. I have a poco C# file which get values of username and password after button click. This C# poco file has nothing to do with a form file. it is separate poco file which will handle login authentication
3. Now poco file will generate result say "Login successful" or "Login Failed"
4. Now, how to display this result of poco file on winform?

Please give proper code which will clear my concept.

Thank you

Comment: have you tried any code... ?

Comment: yes, poco means a class file. But i dont know how to do that. cause whenever i click on button data goes to class file but dont know how to send result of that file to form

Comment: @Akshay You need to do more research and give some sample code of where you face the problem. Please go through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ok wait il post code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the click handler of the button, the authentication method of your authentication class (POCO file as you call it) can be called and the result can be displayed in any way, for example with a message box:

```
var loginResult = Authenticator.Authenticate(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text, out userInfo);

if (loginResult == LoginResult.Success)
{
  // hide the authentication form, or unlock menu, toolbars, ...
}
else
{
  MessageBox.Show("Invalid user name or password");
  // the user stays on the login form and needs to press the login button again for another attempt
}
```

The authenticator class could look llike:

```
public enum LoginResult
{
  Success,
  InvalidUserNameOrPasword,
}

public class UserInfo
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  publi string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Authenticator
{
  public LoginResult Authenticate(string userName, string password, out userInfo)
  {
    // the logic to load the user from DB
  } 
}
```

Comment: ok u mean successfulAuthentication will be static in class file? and if it is set then it will enter in if clause? will try

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have a method with name `Authenticate` in your POCO class that takes userid and pasword and authenticate it. specify the return type of this method as `bool`. When authentication was success then return `true` and otherwise `false`. Now in the button click event write the code as follows. I assume the name of userid textbox as `TxtUserId` and Password Textbox as `TxtPwd` and you have a label just below the button with name `LblError` to display error message when authentication fails.

```
bool success=POCOClassName/object.Authenticate(TxtUserId.Text,TxtPwd.Text);
if(success)
{
     //write the code to display a form that is accessible to authenticated users
}
else
{
     LblError.Text="UserId and or Password Is Wrong";
}
```

Comment: thank you verry much. This is what i was looking for but wasnt getting propoer flow.. Thank you verry much. Is it possible to achieve this using interface or something?

Comment: Please accept this as answer by clicking on the tick mark below the down arrow key on left of my answer. Thank you.